# The resource 'Microsoft.Web/resourceGroups/*' is not defined in the template

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create a ARM deployment that creates or updates the Resource Group, App Service Plan, Application Insights, and the App Service.

I am using Azure Pipelines to do this deployment with the scope of Subscription.

None of these resource exist yet, just the subscription. I have put the `dependsOn` value on all resources other than the Resource Group so to my understanding it should create it first.

```yaml
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "application": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "north europe",
        "west europe"
      ]
    },
    "environment": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "dev",
        "fea",
        "int",
        "pre",
        "prd"
      ]
    },
    "severity": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "low",
        "medium",
        "high",
        "critical"
      ]
    },
    "hostingPlanSkuTier": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Basic",
        "Standard"
      ]
    },
    "hostingPlanSkuName": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "B1",
        "B2",
        "B3",
        "S1",
        "S2",
        "S3"
      ]
    },
    "hostingPlanSkuCapacity": {
      "type": "int"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "resourceGroup": "[concat('rg-', parameters('application'), '-', parameters('environment'), '-', first(first(split(parameters('location'), ' '))), first(last(split(parameters('location'), ' '))))]",
    "appServicePlan": "[concat('asp-', parameters('application'), '-', parameters('environment'), '-', first(first(split(parameters('location'), ' '))), first(last(split(parameters('location'), ' '))))]",
    "appService": "[concat('as-', parameters('application'), '-', parameters('environment'), '-', first(first(split(parameters('location'), ' '))), first(last(split(parameters('location'), ' '))))]",
    "ApplicationInsights": "[concat('ai-', parameters('application'), '-', parameters('environment'), '-', first(first(split(parameters('location'), ' '))), first(last(split(parameters('location'), ' '))))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "[variables('resourceGroup')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
        "severity": "[parameters('severity')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[variables('appServicePlan')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/resourceGroups', variables('resourceGroup'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
        "severity": "[parameters('severity')]"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuName')]",
        "tier": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuTier')]",
        "size": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuName')]",
        "family": "B",
        "capacity": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuCapacity')]"
      },
      "kind": "app",
      "properties": {
        "zoneRedundant": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
      "name": "[variables('ApplicationInsights')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/resourceGroups', variables('resourceGroup'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
        "severity": "[parameters('severity')]"
      },
      "kind": "web",
      "properties": {
        "Application_Type": "web"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[variables('appService')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('resourceGroup'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('resourceGroup'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
        "severity": "[parameters('severity')]"
      },
      "kind": "app",
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlan'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(variables('ApplicationInsights'), '2020-02-02').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~2"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If that depends on is about resource group, then it should be "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups" and not 'Microsoft.Web/resourceGroups'

Answer (score 0):

> The resource 'Microsoft.Web/resourceGroups/*' is not defined

From your ARM template, you are defining the resource type: `Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups` as the first resource.

To set the dependsOn field in the next resources, you need to call this resource id: `Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups`

For example:

```
 "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "[variables('resourceGroup')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": {
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
        "severity": "[parameters('severity')]"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[variables('appServicePlan')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups', variables('resourceGroup'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "environment": "[parameters('environment')]",
        "severity": "[parameters('severity')]"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuName')]",
        "tier": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuTier')]",
        "size": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuName')]",
        "family": "B",
        "capacity": "[parameters('hostingPlanSkuCapacity')]"
      },
      "kind": "app",
      "properties": {
        "zoneRedundant": false
      }
    },
```